# PostgreSQL, Add Unique Constraint to Existing Table without Downtime/Locking

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to figure out the best way to go about adding a new varchar column to an existing table in a PostgreSQL database that doesn't acquire a table lock or require downtime.

I know that I can add an index concurrently which will prevent a lock.

`CREATE UNIQUE INDEX CONCURRENTLY IF NOT EXISTS "my_unique_index" ON "my_table" USING ("my_column", varchar_pattern_ops)`

What I am not sure of, and can't deduce from the docs is if the constraint operation will acquire a lock on the table if the unique index already exists.

`ALTER TABLE "my_table" ADD CONSTRAINT "my_unique_constraint" UNIQUE USING INDEX "my_unique_index";`

I saw in the docs that the `NOT VALID` option is not useful for unique constraints.

Any recommendations would be great.

Comment: Why would you do `ALTER TABLE "my_table" ADD CONSTRAINT "my_unique_constraint" ...` when you have already done `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX CONCURRENTLY IF NOT EXISTS "my_unique_index" ...`? That is duplicating the `UNIQUE("my_column")`.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver To create a foreign key pointing to that constraint? A constraint is more than a unique index.

Comment: A `UNIQUE INDEX` will work for a FK reference as well, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method of first creating a unique index `CONCURRENTLY` and then adding a constraint based on that index is good. The `ALTER TABLE` will require an `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` lock, but that will only be held for a very short time. That won't be a problem unless you always have long running transactions in your database – but in that case you already have a problem.